# WCF error when converting datetime to json format

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I have a WCF service that returns JSON.

Since this morning, I started to get the following error:

```
DateTime values that are greater than DateTime.MaxValue or smaller than DateTime.MinValue when converted to UTC cannot be serialized to JSON
```

Just for the test, I passed today's date to all the DateTime variables that are being returned using JSON, but I stil get the same error.

The code is around 2k rows, so I see no value in posting it here.

Any idea how to solve it??

Comment: You might want to edit in some sample code, and maybe the culture you're currently working in (could be that the date is formatted incorrectly).

Answer (score 6):

I suspect you have a `DateTime` value that is uninitialized - defaults to `DateTime.MinValue` local time.  This can not be converted to UTC if your local timezone is ahead of UTC, because doing so would result in a negative `Ticks` value.

Either find the uninitialized value and correct it, or [move to the USA](http://lp.green-card-us.org/AllSites/1436/Pages/site/LandingPage.asp) :)

Another solution might be to use a nullable value (`DateTime?` in place of `DateTime`).

This defaults to `null` rather than `DateTime.MinValue`, so you should be able to serialize an uninitialized value.